# Appending directory with a list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get a list of grants based on database role to re-use in one of the modules. For that the result needs to be a list

```
name: adding permissions
module:
  role: database_role
  permissions:
    - "schema:USAGE/table1:SELECT/table2:SELECT,UPDATE"
    - "another_schema:USAGE/ALL:ALL"
```

My permissions are defined as variables as follows:

```
db_roles:
  - name: role1
    grants:
      - schema: schema
        permissions:
          - table1:SELECT
          - table2:SELECT,UPDATE
      - schema: another_schema:
        permissions:
          - ALL:ALL
```

I have more roles defined as well. This definition of roles means I can add a new permission per row, making it more readable.

Now I'm trying to format this variable to receive something like this:

```
permissions:
  - role1: 
      - "schema:USAGE/table1:SELECT/table2:SELECT,UPDATE"
      - "another_schema:USAGE/ALL:ALL"
  - role2: 
      - "schema:USAGE/ALL:ALL"
```

But I have no idea how to get to this result.

**What I've tried**

So far the furthest I got is this but I'm not sure if it's possible to retrieve the values from the dictionary somehow

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"permissions": {
    "role1": {
        "schema": "schema:USAGE/table1:SELECT/table2:SELECT",
        "another_schema": "another_schema:USAGE/ALL:ALL"
    }
}
```

}

The code that got me there is:

```
- name: Create privs for users
  set_fact:
      permissions: "{{ permissions|default( {item.0.name:{}} ) | combine( {item.0.name:{item.1.schema: item.1.schema ~ ':USAGE/'  ~ item.1.permissions | join('/')}}, recursive=True) }}"
  with_subelements:
      - "{{ db_roles }}"
      - grants
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tough one :) hope i got it right.

picking up where you left off, i added this task, to further process the variable you prepared:

```
  - name: Create privs for users - step 2
    set_fact:
      permissions_final: "{{ permissions_final|default([]) + [{ item : permissions[item] | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | list }] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ permissions.keys() | list }}"
```

full code and sample output:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    db_roles:
    - name: role1
      grants:
        - schema: schema
          permissions:
            - table1:SELECT
            - table2:SELECT,UPDATE
        - schema: another_schema
          permissions:
            - ALL:ALL
    - name: role2
      grants:
        - schema: schema3
          permissions:
            - table1:SELECT
            - table2:SELECT,UPDATE
        - schema: another_schema4
          permissions:
            - ALL:ALL

  tasks:
  - name: Create privs for users
    set_fact:
      permissions: "{{ permissions|default( {item.0.name:{}} ) | combine( {item.0.name:{item.1.schema: item.1.schema ~ ':USAGE/'  ~ item.1.permissions | join('/')}}, recursive=True) }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ db_roles }}"
      - grants

  # - name: print results
  #   debug:
  #     var: permissions

  - name: Create privs for users - step 2
    set_fact:
      permissions_final: "{{ permissions_final|default([]) + [{ item : permissions[item] | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | list }] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ permissions.keys() | list }}"

  - name: print results
    debug:
      var: permissions_final
```

variable produced:

```
TASK [print results] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "permissions_final": [
        {
            "role1": [
                "schema:USAGE/table1:SELECT/table2:SELECT,UPDATE",
                "another_schema:USAGE/ALL:ALL"
            ]
        },
        {
            "role2": [
                "schema3:USAGE/table1:SELECT/table2:SELECT,UPDATE",
                "another_schema4:USAGE/ALL:ALL"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: hey all worked fine for me with .values() thanks :)